# htaccess to rewrite the original URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am creating SEO friendly URLs for my website. I have a file notfound.php to which I am redirecting all the URLs. Now, I want notfound.php to search for the URL in database and generate the corresponding content.

But the problem is that in the URL it shows is `http://some_url/notfound.php`
I don't want this URL to be displayed in the address bar, instead I want the original one.

For example,

`http://some_url/hello/world` is redirecting to `http://some_url/notfound.php` using `ErrorDocument 404`
and notfound.php is serving the content

But how to show `http://some_url/hello/world` in the URL instead of notfound.php? And, is this the right way to redirect and rewrite while matching the URLs from a database?

Comment: What configuration is doing the redirecting?

Comment: Also, if you don't serve a 404 response for a clearly missing page ("/blah/123/blah/234.txt"), I believe that can hurt your rankings.

Comment: I am using .htaccess file in my root folder to redirect.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post the actual redirect config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must have mod_rewrite enabled, then you can try:

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ notfound.php [L]
```

the first two lines ensure that you can still load things that exist (like js and css files that you may need)

Comment: np, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

ErrorDocument does an external redirect when you give it a complete URL.  The doc tells you how to do an internal redirect.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/custom-error.html#configuration

Comment: Thank you, I was using an external redirect. I changed it to internal.